# Xcode issue with C++

Tags: xcode

So I've recently started using XCode and have an issue with trying to compile C++ code: Even a basic program like

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter a value for X: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "X is " + x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives me no output (under "All Output" I get):

```
Enter a value for X: 
5
```

Comment: did you try to add std::flush after last std::endl ?

Comment: just did -- no change in issue

Comment: thats because you are concatenating `int` with a `string`. Try using `std::cout<<"X is "<<x<<std::endl;`